# EntityFramework groupby not working as on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following sql query

```
SELECT  statusId, statusName,sum(durationSeconds)/3600 as duration
    FROM status
    where date_local >=date
    and durationSeconds > 0
    group by statusId
    order by duration desc;
```

I'm trying to do the same using EF core.

```
  var result = await context.status
            .Where(e => e.ShiftdateLocal >= date && e.Durationseconds > 0)
            .Select(e => new LiveStatusProductionViewModel
            { StatusId = e.statusId, StatusName = e.statusName, Duration = e.Durationseconds / 3600 })
            //.GroupBy(e => e.Duration)
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.Duration)
            .ToListAsync();
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I achieve the same result as on mysql?

Comment: What you posted is an ugly MySQL quirk that's not officially supported and prone to 10x performance degradation from one MySQL *minor* version to the next

Comment: BTW EF Core generates SQL statements. It doesn't change how the database works. The MySQL provider you used simply doesn't allow such unsupported syntax. If you used MySQL's own provider, well, they don't like that syntax either

Comment: BTW the values returned by the non-group rows are essentially undefined. The server is free to return whatever data is more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have did only half of work, added `GroupBy` but not added correct projection.

```
var result = await context.status
        .Where(e => e.ShiftdateLocal >= date && e.Durationseconds > 0)
        .GroupBy(e => new { e.statusId, e.statusName })
        .Select(g => new LiveStatusProductionViewModel
        { 
           StatusId = g.Key.statusId, 
           StatusName = g.Key.statusName, 
           Duration = g.Sum(x => x.Durationseconds / 3600)
        })
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.Duration)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: The OP is using a semi-unsupported MySQL quirk to return non-Group columns in the SELECT query. What you posted, which is the *correct* way to group, groups by bog the id and name

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes I know that MySQL uses such quirks and I'm trying to avoid non-complete grouping.